# Using multiple frameworks gives clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, duplicates, clang

Like I'm saying.. I'm using two frameworks, FlashIz and MWPhotoBrowser. (Actually I'm using more, but they don't give errors..)

When building the project, I got errors like this:

```
    Ld /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gTicket.app/gTicket normal armv7
    cd /Users/Korneel/Documents/stage-genius/trunk/IOS/gTicket
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Korneel/Documents/stage-genius/trunk/IOS/gTicket/FlashizEmbeddedLibrary.embeddedframwork -filelist /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Intermediates/gTicket.build/Debug-iphoneos/gTicket.build/Objects-normal/armv7/gTicket.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMWPhotoBrowser.a -framework MapKit -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MessageUI -framework FlashizEmbeddedLibrary -framework ImageIO -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTapkuLibrary.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Intermediates/gTicket.build/Debug-iphoneos/gTicket.build/Objects-normal/armv7/gTicket_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/gTicket.app/gTicket

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBProgressHUD.mode in:
    /Users/Korneel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gTicket-grnuygifaetsfmbdncixojogumle/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMWPhotoBrowser.a(MBProgressHUD.o)
    /Users/Korneel/Documents/stage-genius/trunk/IOS/gTicket/FlashizEmbeddedLibrary.embeddedframwork/FlashizEmbeddedLibrary.framework/FlashizEmbeddedLibrary(MBProgressHUD.o)



ld: 29 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, I derived from this error that those two frameworks are using the same 'frameworks' like MBProgressHUD. So I thought of removing 1 of those? But I don't know how.. 
Is there anyone who had a similar problem? The problem is, I can't seem to find this files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is **duplication**. `MBProgressHUD` have added twice(from `libMWPhotoBrowser.a` and `FlashizEmbeddedLibrary`)

So Remove from any one of those libs.

Comment: How to do this? Can I remove it from libMWPhotoBrowser.a?

Comment: You cann't remove it from library file `libMWPhotoBrowser.a`. But you can use source from here https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser. and remove from there.

Comment: so, when i import the project, (source files) and I remove the MBProgressHud (the directory), XCodes gives my a build error: He does'nt find MBProgressHUD.h?

Comment: Did you have source file for this `FlashizEmbeddedLibrary`? If NO, above error will rise. because if it's library, that source couldn't share with `MWPhotoBrowser`...

Comment: No I have no source files for FlashizEmbeddedLibrary, I think I solved the problem by unclicking checkmark next to target membership (my project), on the MBProgressHUD.m file over there.

Comment: So you maynot use any one above libs.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that it was due to duplicate symbol. In your project there are multiple classes of `MBProgressHUD`. Please use only one class and remove other. This will resolve your problem,

Comment: I would like to know how.. Because if i remove the framework from the MWPhotoBrowser subproject, it doesn't build either?

Comment: MWPhotoBrowser is created by your own or some one else?? Means you have source code of it.

Comment: MWPhotoBrowser is created by someone else. its a premade framework.